# Ideal diode circuit with two AC sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

Consider the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDpnvM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with \$ V_{1}=100\sin(\omega t)\$ [V] and \$V_{2}=45\sin(\omega t)\$ [V]. Assuming we have an **ideal** diode,

> The goal is to compute the peak-to-peak value of the voltage \$V_{3}\$ which lies between NODE1 and NODE2

Assuming the diode is conducting, it appears that \$V_3 = V_1 = 100\sin(\omega t)\$. Now this is true only for \$T/2\$ of the total cycle time. Assuming that the diode is reverse biased, I don't know what to do in such case to proceed.

> The correct answer is **145 V**

For the period between \$T/2\$ and \$T\$ of the input time cycle, this would imply that the diode is reverse biased and can this be modelled as an open switch so technically, we can remove \$V_1\$ as well which leaves us with the other part of the circuit. If we perform a KVL we should get \$V_3=45\text{ V}\$ so does this mean that overall we have 100 + 45 = 145 V for one complete period of the input cycle time? which would then solve the problem? I believe there is some mistake in my argument, though.

Comment: At least you are lucky your sources are in phase… the core idea is correct. You do one analysis with the diode shorted (V1 is positive), and one when the diode open (V1 is negative). However you're talking about some V3 you didn't mention in the schematic. What's the issue exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the diagram below, at time \$t = \frac{1}{4}T\$, both signals \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ are at their maximum, where:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_1 &= 100V \\
V_2 &= 45V
\end{aligned}
$$

Since \$V_1 > V_2\$, at this point D1 is forward biased. If we assume it's an ideal diode, it's fully conductive, and the there's no voltage across it, and node A must be at the same potential as \$V_1\$:

$$ V_A = V_1 = +100V$$

At time \$t = \frac{3}{4}T\$, both signals are at their minimum, where:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_1 &= -100V \\
V_2 &= -45V
\end{aligned}
$$

The diode D1 is now reversed biased, because \$V_2 > V_1\$. This is where my explanation differs from your "Edit 1". D1 has effectively infinite resistance, and can be removed from the circuit with no effect.

Another, more technically sound way of describing this state, is to think of the combination of R1 and D1 in series having infinite combined resistance, through which no current can flow.

With no current flowing through R1, by Ohm's law, the voltage across R1 is zero:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= I \times R_1 \\
&= 0A \times 2k\Omega \\
&= 0V
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore node A is at the same potential as \$V_2\$:

$$ V_A = V_2 = -45V $$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7p328.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since \$V_A\$ swings between extremes of +100V and -45V, and \$V_B\$ remains always at 0V, the voltage between A and B has a peak-to-peak amplitude of 145V.